# How can I monitor the stack usage of a java application

Tags: java, performance, stack, jconsole, jvisualvm

I'm working on a Java application which is running very slowly. In order to increase the performance, I would like to monitor it first.

Using `jvisualm` I can monitor the heap size of my Java application, and `jconsole` - both tools are present in the JDK's `bin` folder - I can see the "Non-Heap Memory Usage", but as my application seems to contain quite some recursive calls, I'd like to know the amount of stack which is used.

Does anybody know a tool which allows me to monitor this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if YourKit has it (https://www.yourkit.com/) but it will show you in what methods most time is spent.

Comment: YourKit will show the non-heap memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.yourkit.com/ . It will show you the use of non-heap memory also. Trial version of this is available for 14 days.